# Move several SKSpriteNode in array with delay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have a problem with moving several nodes in array. There is a code:

```
SKSpriteNode* paddle = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName: paddleXCategoryName];

SKAction *move = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(paddle.position.x, CGRectGetMaxY(self.scene.frame)) duration:1.5];

NSMutableArray *shots = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *shot = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"shoot.png"];
    shot.size = CGSizeMake(2, 5);

    shot.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(2, 6)];
    shot.physicsBody.categoryBitMask    = shotCategory;
    shot.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = blockCategory;
    shot.physicsBody.collisionBitMask   = blockCategory;

    [shots addObject:shot];
}

int i = 0;
for (SKSpriteNode *shot in shots) {
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.2+0.3*i];
    shot.position = paddle.position;
    [self addChild:shot];
    [shot runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, move]] completion:^{
        [shot removeFromParent];
    }];
}
```

I have only one node moving. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all of your nodes are moving together without delay to the same point. This is because you are not incrementing your `i` variable inside the loop. Try the code below. For the SKAction to work properly also set `affectedByGravity` to false.

```
int i = 0;
for (SKSpriteNode *shot in shots) {
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.2+0.3*i];
    shot.position = paddle.position;
    [self addChild:shot];
    shot.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false; // Added line.
    [shot runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, move]] completion:^{
        [shot removeFromParent];
    }];

    i++; // Added line.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They all run the same move action. Each sprite needs to run its own copy of the action. Try changing the runAction statement by replacing `move` with `[move copy]`:

```
[shot runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, [move copy]]] completion:^{
    [shot removeFromParent];
}];
```